# Renting digital services to Jews who are known to work on Shabbes

Tags: halacha, shabbat, heterodox, business

Given the following scenario:

A Jew is the sole owner of a digital business which rents its services (a digital platform that does not require human intervention from part of the owner) for a monthly fee. The owner of the company is [shomer Shabat](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shomer_Shabbat) and no one in the company works on Shabbes.

Within the pool of clients there are some who are also Jewish, but use the rented system on Shabbes.

What **halachic** and **moral** considerations should the owner take into account for the previous case? What is the responsibility of the owner towards his Jewish brothers in such circumstances?

Comment: This is interesting. I remember that the ATMs near kikar shabbat didn't operate after shabbos since there were servers in America that could be affected. Not identical to your question, but perhaps related. You need to make sure that you aren't a michshol, but a standard disclaimer should take care of that. If a person is determined to violate shabbos, there's not much you can do... Does the use of the rented system itself constitute melachah? If not, then you aren't causing any forbidden action...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky if the Jew used the system he would have to operate either a computer or a phone, so it would constitute a melachah.

Comment: They would ALREADY have to be operating those things in order to use your system. Not your responsibility. As long as your service isn't itself a melacha, I fail to see how your responsible...